# Error al insertar datos

Tags: php

ayer hice una consulta para agregar un input o textarea dependiando un input radio. Ahora estoy tratando de guardar uno de esos datos y solo me deja guardad uno.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
if(!empty($_POST['tipo']) && !empty($_POST['img']) && !empty($_POST['txt'])){
    $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO notas (tipo, tiponota) VALUES (:tipo, :tiponota)");
    $add->bindValue(':tipo', ($_POST['tipo']));
    $add->bindValue(':tiponota', ($_POST['post']));
    $add->bindValue(':tiponota', ($_POST['img']));
    $add->execute();
    echo "bien";
}
else{
    echo "mal";
}
}
?>
```

```css
/* oculto los elementos */
input.i-text, textarea {display: none;}
/* lo muestros si está seleccionado value=imagen */
input.i-radio[value="img"]:checked ~ input.i-text {display: block;}
/* lo muestros si está seleccionado value=texto */
input.i-radio[value="txt"]:checked ~ textarea {display: block;}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="tipo" class="i-radio" value="txt">&#91;text&#93;
<input type="radio" name="tipo" class="i-radio" value="img">&#91;image&#93;<br>
<input type="text" name="img" class="i-text inputI" placeholder="URL image"><br>
<textarea name="post" placeholder="Nota de credito"></textarea><br>
<button name="add">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Por lo que se ve, intentas mandar dos valores a la misma columna (tipo nota: post e img) Entonces tus opciones son: agregar una tercera columna o mandar únicamente 2 parámetros en lugar de 3.

Comment: Si, voy a tener que hacer eso... me la complique solo... je, gracias